# ASP.NET Dynamic Menu to a set width and starting location

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, menu

I am creating a Menu in ASP.NET and I want the dynamic part of the Menu to start from the left and have a set width no matter which part of the static menu you are hovering over. Please see the image below to help aid in what I am trying to say.

[image]

When you hover over "Portfolio" I want it to start from 0px on the left, the same as "service". It needs to have a set width too so it ends at the end of "stories".

I have tried looking online for tips but I haven't come across anything to help. I have also tried playing with the "Position" elements but nothing I do seems to work so I am hoping I can pointed towards a working example or just some example that may help me.

I don't suppose you can use CSS to style each individual sub menu separately?

I haven't linked any code because it is quite simply just an ASP menu but if any is required please don't hesitate to ask.

Edit: Is there a way to do this through pure CSS/HTML?

Comment: Have you tried looking for a plugin ? There's tons of free CSS and jquery menu that does this. You can inspirate yourself from the code of the plugin.

Comment: I must admit I have never used a plugin. I will have a look around and see what I can find. Thanks for your input.